# How to make a button call an id from database

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

i am trying to make a button that can be used to generate an id from the database when clicked, but nothing is showing up.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-small btn-success" onclick=" detailsmodal(<?= $products['id']; ?>) ">Details</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function detailsmodal(id) {
    alert(id);
  }
</script>
```

Nothing is showing when I click the button and I get an error saying:

> SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'

Comment: The error implies that your PHP code is not being interpreted. If you view the source of the page do you see `<?= $products['id']; ?>` in it, or the value it output?

Comment: Is id a number or  string also?

Comment: i see the value it output if i view the source of the page